# Passing the user information to the mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Post which has many comments. I am trying to send a notification email to the owner of the post that someone has commented on their post but I am having a hard time trying to get the owner of the post to the mailer. the code if as follows

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create

    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully posted an offer."
      PostMailer.comment_posted(----).deliver #this is the mail code
      redirect_to @commentable
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error adding an offer."
    end
  end
end
```

below is the mailer code

```
class PostMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "contact@example.com"

  def comment_posted(user)
    @user = user

    mail to: user.first_name, subject: "You have a new Comment!"
  end
end
```

below is the comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  has_ancestry
end
```

and the Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, dependent: :destroy 
end
```

Comment: So what's exactly wrong?

Comment: i want to get the post user so that I can pass the email through the mailer to notify them of the comment

Comment: It all depends on your models' realtions. Please show what is commentable, and what models is it associated to.

Comment: I just edited the question above and added the models

Comment: Why does the PostMailer method is called offer_posted? You're calling PostMailer.comment_posted in the CommentsController.

Comment: it was a typo in this question but I checked my code and its okay

Comment: is  @commentable the original post?  In that case you should be doing something like `PostMailer.comment_posted(@comment.commentable.user).deliver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
PostMailer.comment_posted(@commentable.user).deliver
```

`@commentable` will give you corresponding `Post` record for the given comment. **Post belongs_to a user**, so you can access the poster using `@commentable.user`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the controller you are doing:

```
PostMailer.comment_posted
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
PostMailer.offer_posted(@comment.user).deliver
```

?

Comment: it was a typo in this question but in my code its correct, I just fixed it